# How to Redirect each link on the webpage through another link using Javascript or any html?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, url-rewriting, redirect

How to Redirect each link on the webpage through another link using JavaScript or any html?

I have a website - www.example.com

I have few links on each page like -

- www.link1.com
- www.link2.com
- www.link3.com

I want the javascript that can be added to each webpage and will give the below results -

whenever someone clicks on the links - it should show a link like this - www.example.com/redirect?=www.link1.com

Now this redirect script should calculate the redirect path based on links like and whenever some user clicks on them it should go like below-

link1 should be redirected as below - 
www.affiliate1.com/r/www.link1.com

and link2 should be like below - 
www.affiliate2.com/r/www.link2.com

Please advise on ow to achieve this. I am not a code expert but I have few websites where they are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var remember = [].slice;
var to = 'a';
var post = document.getElementsByTagName(to);
var relevant = remember.call(post);
var code = 'https://example.com?redirect=';

relevant.forEach(function(atag) {
  var href = atag.href;

  if ( href ) {
    atag.href = code + encodeURIComponent(href);
  }
});
```

Comment: I haven't seen this pattern before. Whats the benefit of converting to an Array as apposed to just iterating over the HTML collection?

Comment: @Austin Nothing except that i get a "free" closure from `.forEach` and all of the other array methods available. `for-i-len` would by far be faster.

Comment: @Austin Well.. and this will create a "snapshot" of the DOM, while a HTMLCollection is live and will represent the DOM before/after insert/remove

Comment: hi, I only know simple HTML, please advise on how this code will work. and where I can define conditions for different websites