# How to redirect any specific link on the page to a specific url?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, redirect

How to redirect any specific link on the page to a specific url?

I have a webpage and it contains several links.

- link1.com (20 links)
- link2.com (15 links)
- link3.com (8 links)

I want that whenever someone clicks on link1.com he gets redirected to www.example.com

Please advise how I can acheieve this.

With the below code I can do a redirect for a current page on screen. But I need to do it for every link on my website.

Comment: <script>

var hasC1  = window.location.href.indexOf('redirect')!=-1
var hasC2  = window.location.href.indexOf('Test')!=-1
var newLoc = hasC1 
               ? hasC2 ? "https://website.com/" : 'http://www.example.in'
               : hasC2 ? window.location.href+'append1' : '';

if (newLoc)
    window.location = newLoc;

</script>

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Redirect each link on the webpage through another link using Javascript or any html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29774574/how-to-redirect-each-link-on-the-webpage-through-another-link-using-javascript-o)

Comment: that was my separate question. I would also like to know the resolution for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some sample code. You can edit the redirects variable to match your needs. The index of the redirects variable is a regular expression, if it matches the link gets redirected.

**option 1**

```
<a href="http://link1.com">link 1</a>
<a href="http://link2.com/alsoredirected">link 2</a>
<a href="http://wikipedia.org">not redirected</a>

<script>
var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var redirects = {
    "http://link1.com": "http://google.com",
    "link2.com": "http://google.com"
};

for(var i = 0;i < aTags.length; i++) {
    aTags[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        var url = this.getAttribute("href");

        for (var redirect in redirects) {
            var pattern = new RegExp(redirect);

            if (pattern.test(url)) {
                window.location = redirects[redirect];
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

**option 2**

This is the preferred solution as it replaces the href attribute if necessary. Thus you do not have to check the redirects on every click.

```
<a href="http://link1.com">link 1</a>
<a href="http://link2.com/alsoredirected">link 2</a>
<a href="http://wikipedia.org">not redirected</a>

<script>
var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var redirects = {
    "http://link1.com": "http://google.com",
    "link2.com": "http://google.com"
};

for(var i = 0;i < aTags.length; i++) {
    var url = aTags[i].getAttribute("href");

    for (var redirect in redirects) {
        var pattern = new RegExp(redirect);

        if (pattern.test(url)) {
            aTags[i].setAttribute("href", redirects[redirect]);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: How to use a wildcard in the link1.

Comment: I edited the answer. You can now enter any regular expression as index in the redirects variable. If the regular expression matches it gets redirected.

Comment: Is it possible to add link specific redirect in the 2nd example -

www.Link1.com/abc/ced : www.redirect.com/www.Link1.com/abc/ced

www.Link2.com/z/x : www.linkme.com/www.Link2.com/z/x

I tried adding variables but unable to add subfolders in the link url to the redirect.